# OpenGL, FreeType2: символы перекрывают друг друга

Tags: c++, opengl, текст, glsl

Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку FreeType (v2) для 2Д отрисовки в OpenGL (v4.1) сцене на языке C++. Текст отображается, но не правильно, символы друг друга коряво перекрывают. Как это починить? Мой код отрисовки:

```
void CFreeTypeFont::Print(string sText, int x, int y, int iPXSize) {
    glBindVertexArray(uiVAO);
    glUniform1i(shp->uniform("gSampler"), 0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    int iCurX = x, iCurY = y;
    if(iPXSize == -1)iPXSize = iLoadedPixelSize;
    float fScale = float(iPXSize)/float(iLoadedPixelSize);
    FOR(i, ESZ(sText)) {
        if(sText[i] == '\n') {
            iCurX = x;
            iCurY -= iNewLine*iPXSize/iLoadedPixelSize;
            continue;
        }
        int iIndex = int(sText[i]);
        iCurX += iBearingX[iIndex]*iPXSize/iLoadedPixelSize;
        if(sText[i] != ' ') {
            tCharTextures[iIndex].BindTexture(0);
            glm::mat4 mModelView = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(float(iCurX), float(iCurY), 0.0f));
            mModelView = glm::scale(mModelView, glm::vec3(fScale));

            glUniformMatrix4fv(shp->uniform("matrices.modelViewMatrix"),
                               1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mModelView));

            // Draw character
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, iIndex*4, 4);
        }

        iCurX += (iAdvX[iIndex]-iBearingX[iIndex])*iPXSize/iLoadedPixelSize;
    }
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Вывод такой:

[Должно быть "Hellow, World!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTmTA.png)

Если отключить `blend mode`, то хорошо видны границы символов:

[Тот же текст без прозрачности](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1P3q.png)

**Код вершинного шейдера:**

```
#version 410

uniform struct Matrices {
    mat4 modelViewMatrix;
} matrices;

uniform float screenWidth;
uniform float screenHeight;

layout (location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    texCoord = inCoord;
    vec4 pre = matrices.modelViewMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    pre.x = pre.x / screenWidth - 1;
    pre.y = pre.y / screenHeight - 1;
    gl_Position = pre;
}
```

**Фрагментный шейдер:**

```
#version 410

in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D gSampler;
uniform vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vec4 vTexColor = texture(gSampler, texCoord);
    outputColor = vTexColor*vColor;
}
```

Comment: А вы рисуете каждую буквы отдельным прямоугольником? Может быть вам легче создать текстуру с целым словом и её выводить?

Comment: Может дело в keming? )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В английской версии [мне подсказали](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48664176/9327488), что этот артефакт возникает при включенной проверке глубины.

Это все из-за того, что при отрисовке глифа, его непрозрачная часть все же пишется в буфер глубины, и, соответственно, другой глиф в эту же область уже не может отрисоваться, т.к. имеет ту же глубины (и проваливает тест глубины).

Если добавить `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` то отрисовка текста происходит корректно.

Альтернативное решение - использовать ALPHA_TEST чтобы рисовать только непрозрачные тексели.